# Error in main QueryYou have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, database

I am a beginner in PHP. I am getting this error whenever I am trying to upload a file through the browser.

"Error in main QueryYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '',OTHER_PAYMENT='',TOTAL_CASH_OUTFLOW=''' at line 1"

I am unable to identify where I am going wrong. Here is my code for inserting values

```
<?php

class Common { public function uploadData($connection,$SL_NO,$PROGRAM,$STATE,$BRANCH,$OPENING_BALANCE,$CASH_RECEIVED_FROM_OTHER_BRANCH,$DISBURSEMENT_CASH_WITHDRAWAL,$CASH_COLLECTION,$ONLINE_COLLECTION,$PRE_SETTLEMENT,$INSURANCE,$LPF_GST,$OTHER_COLLECTION,$TOTAL_CASH_INFLOW,$CASH_REMITTED_TO_OTHER_BRANCH,$CASH_DISBURSEMENT,$CASHLESS_DISBURSEMENT,$CASH_DEPOSITED,$BANK_NAME,$ACCOUNT_NO,$OTHER_PAYMENT,$TOTAL_CASH_OUTFLOW) { $mainQuery = "INSERT INTO exceldata SET 

SL_NO='$SL_NO',PROGRAM='$PROGRAM',STATE='$STATE',BRANCH='$BRANCH',OPENING_BALANCE='$OPENING_BALANCE',CASH_RECEIVED_FROM_OTHER_BRANCH='$CASH_RECEIVED_FROM_OTHER_BRANCH',DISBURSEMENT_CASH_WITHDRAWAL='$DISBURSEMENT_CASH_WITHDRAWAL',CASH_COLLECTION='$CASH_COLLECTION',ONLINE_COLLECTION='$ONLINE_COLLECTION',PRE_SETTLEMENT='$PRE_SETTLEMENT',INSURANCE='$INSURANCE',LPF_GST='$LPF_GST',LPF_GST='$LPF_GST',OTHER_COLLECTION='$OTHER_COLLECTION',TOTAL_CASH_INFLOW='$TOTAL_CASH_INFLOW',CASH_REMITTED_TO_OTHER_BRANCH='$CASH_REMITTED_TO_OTHER_BRANCH',CASH_DISBURSEMENT='$CASH_DISBURSEMENT',CASHLESS_DISBURSEMENT='$CASHLESS_DISBURSEMENT',CASH_DEPOSITED='$CASH_DEPOSITED',BANK_NAME='$BANK_NAME',ACCOUNT_NO='$ACCOUNT_NO,OTHER_PAYMENT='$OTHER_PAYMENT',TOTAL_CASH_OUTFLOW='$TOTAL_CASH_OUTFLOW'"; $result1 = $connection->query($mainQuery) or die("Error in main Query".$connection->error); return $result1; } }
```

My script code:

```
<?php
include  "config.php";
include_once  "Common.php";

if($_FILES['excelDoc']['name']) {
    $arrFileName = explode('.', $_FILES['excelDoc']['name']);
    if ($arrFileName[1] == 'csv') {
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['excelDoc']['tmp_name'], "r");
        $count = 0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $count++;
            if ($count == 1) {
                continue;
            }
                $SL_NO = $connection->real_escape_string($data[0]);
                $PROGRAM = $connection->real_escape_string($data[1]);
                $STATE = $connection->real_escape_string($data[2]);
                $BRANCH = $connection->real_escape_string($data[3]);
                $OPENING_BALANCE = $connection->real_escape_string($data[4]);
                $CASH_RECEIVED_FROM_OTHER_BRANCH = $connection->real_escape_string($data[5]);
                $DISBURSEMENT_CASH_WITHDRAWAL = $connection->real_escape_string($data[6]);
                $CASH_COLLECTION = $connection->real_escape_string($data[7]);
                $ONLINE_COLLECTION = $connection->real_escape_string($data[8]);
                $PRE_SETTLEMENT = $connection->real_escape_string($data[9]);
                $INSURANCE = $connection->real_escape_string($data[10]);
                $LPF_GST = $connection->real_escape_string($data[11]);
                $OTHER_COLLECTION = $connection->real_escape_string($data[12]);
                $TOTAL_CASH_INFLOW = $connection->real_escape_string($data[13]);
                $CASH_REMITTED_TO_OTHER_BRANCH = $connection->real_escape_string($data[14]);
                $CASH_DISBURSEMENT = $connection->real_escape_string($data[15]);
                $CASHLESS_DISBURSEMENT = $connection->real_escape_string($data[16]);
                $CASH_DEPOSITED = $connection->real_escape_string($data[17]);
                $BANK_NAME = $connection->real_escape_string($data[18]);
                $ACCOUNT_NO = $connection->real_escape_string($data[19]);
                $OTHER_PAYMENT = $connection->real_escape_string($data[20]);
                $TOTAL_CASH_OUTFLOW = $connection->real_escape_string($data[21]);
                
                $common = new Common();
                
                $SheetUpload = $common->uploadData($connection,$SL_NO,$PROGRAM,$STATE,$BRANCH,$OPENING_BALANCE,$CASH_RECEIVED_FROM_OTHER_BRANCH,$DISBURSEMENT_CASH_WITHDRAWAL,$CASH_COLLECTION,$ONLINE_COLLECTION,$PRE_SETTLEMENT,$INSURANCE,$LPF_GST,$OTHER_COLLECTION,$TOTAL_CASH_INFLOW,$CASH_REMITTED_TO_OTHER_BRANCH,$CASH_DISBURSEMENT,$CASHLESS_DISBURSEMENT,$CASH_DEPOSITED,$BANK_NAME,$ACCOUNT_NO,$OTHER_PAYMENT,$TOTAL_CASH_OUTFLOW);
        }
        if ($SheetUpload){
            echo "<script>alert('Sheet has been uploaded successfull !');window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Always look at right before where they mention the error. In your case, you're missing a quote in `ACCOUNT_NO='$ACCOUNT_NO,OTHER_PAYMENT='$OTHER_PAYMENT',`. If you use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), you would eliminate these types of quoting issues.

Comment: @aynber thank u :)

can u suggest me some sites from where I can taker references and learn php coding??

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any information on that other than using the documentation at https://www.php.net